# NumberFormatException for valid number?

Tags: java

I'm getting this error

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "7708166193"

From this line of code

```
String[] tmp = in.nextLine().replace("-","").split(" ");
String phoneNumber = tmp[2]+tmp[3];
int number = Integer.parseInt(phoneNumber);
```

And I cannot quite figure out why it's throwing this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The largest int (+- 2billion) is smaller than 7708166193. Use:

```
long number = Long.parseLong(phoneNumber)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because, Your input value (i.e `7708166193`) is greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (i.e `2147483647`). Use `long` instead of `int`

```
  long number = Long.parseLong(phoneNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you tried to use a [Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) but you reached the max value that is 2^31, for   **7708166193** you should use [Long](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) instead.